# How to architect handling onSuccess of a redux dispatched request that becomes a React Navigation change of screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have a Registration screen.
The result of a successful registration will update the account store with the state:
`{error: null, token: "acme-auth" ...}`

On the Registration screen I render an `error` if there is one from the store.

What I want to do is navigate to the Dashboard with `this.props.navigation.navigate` when the store state changes.

I can do this hackily:

```
render() {
  const {account} = this.props
  const {token} = account
  if (token) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
  }
}
```

I can also use callbacks:

```
sendRegistration = () => {
   const {email, password} = this.getFormFields()
   this.props.registerStart({email, password, success: this.onRegisterSuccess, failure: this.onRegisterFailure}) //using mapDispatchToProps
}
```

Passing the callback through the redux path seems redundant since I already have the changed state thanks to linking the `account` store to my `Registration` component props.

I am toying with the idea of a top-level renderer that detects a change in a  `userScreen` store then swaps out the appropriate component to render.

Is there a simpler, or better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a better way.  If you want to navigate in an async fashion the best place to do it is directly in the thunk, sagas, etc after the async action is successful.  You can do this by creating a navigation Service that uses the ref from your top level navigator to navigate.

In `app.js`:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  /* ... */
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This sets the ref of the navigator.  Then in your NavigationService file:

```
// NavigationService.js

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Now you have access to the navigator and can navigate from redux directly.  You can use it like this:

```
// any js module
import NavigationService from 'path-to-NavigationService.js';

// ...

NavigationService.navigate(''Dashboard' });
```

Here is the documentation explaining more:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: This looks reasonable, I'll try this. Thank you.